# Class names shown obfuscated in firebase crashlytics dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, crashlytics

I am using proguard in Android with kotlin project and some crashes(not all) appears with class names obfuscated in firebase crashlytics dashboard, why is that happening?

[image: i]

Comment: Have you uploaded the mapping file to crashlytics?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved after upgrading to latest crashlytics firebase version.